# How to filter on a long text just one word via Firestore on Ionic 4?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

I'm trying to filter using (ionChange) on a searchbar just for a word on a long text (body of a letter) using Firestore, but the problem I don't know how to start, cannot see any option using Firestore (The filter is not about <=, ==...)

I was googleing a lot but didn't find any solution. Any idea?

Just what i want is to filter a list of ion-card (retrieved from firestore) just a word from a long text. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Firestore does not support full-text search. So there is currently no way you can search a single word in a very long text. According to the official documentation regarding [full-text search in Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search):

> To enable full text search of your Cloud Firestore data, use a third-party search service like [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/).

If the those words that you want to search can be considered "tags", then store those tags in an array and use `array-contains` option.

Comment: Yeaaah man I already knew that, i think im looking something that doesn't exist jeje

Comment: It exists only through a library. I suggest you give it a try. It works very well.

Comment: For 14 days... im not interested, thank you so much anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer find data from Firesote.

```
 searcData( event ) {
const value = event.target.value;
this.loader.presentLoading();
const fireStoreData = this.afStore
                      .collection('CollectionName', ref => ref
                                  .orderBy('fieldName')
                                  .startAt(value.toLowerCase())
                                  .endAt(value.toLowerCase() + '\uf8ff')
                                  .limit(10)).valueChanges();
fireStoreData.subscribe(data => {
  this.data = data;
  this.loader.hideLoading();
  // console.log(data);
}, err =>{
  this.loader.hideLoading();
  console.log(err);
});
```

}